# Can't list and install xemacs packages under cygwin on windows7

Tags: windows, cygwin, xemacs

I have a fresh install of cygwin and xemacs on my home laptop. I'm trying to get to the packages list in xemacs, but not having much luck.

First of all I was getting an error message telling me "ftp.XXX.com seems not a pty". Following the instructions [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.emacs.xemacs/2007-09/msg00003.html) I was able to tell efs to use lftp, and got past that error.

Now I get told:

`Process not open for writing: #<process "*ftp yyy@ftp.xxx.org*" pid 9999 state:exit>`

Any idea what's going on there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with which ftp you are using.  From the message, I believe you are trying to use the ftp that comes with Windows.  It won't work as the native Windows ftp does not act like a pty.

The best solution I can suggest is to install the Cygwin port of ftp.

Comment: As specified in the OP, I'm telling efs to use lftp from cygwin. That got me past the pty error.

Comment: @tenpn "lftp" is not "ftp".  The EFS (which is what appears to actually run do the work for the packages) has problems with things that aren't a real ftp.  This [thread from the XEmacs list](http://lists.xemacs.org/pipermail/xemacs-beta/2010-May/019541.html) may help you.